# MS Access ODBC connection

Tags: ms-access, web-applications, jdbc, odbc, driver

I am using MS Access as backend for a web application.
Since I am using 64bit OS, I have updated the path to `sysWOW64` in ODBC (Data Sources)...But I still I get an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

The code that I used is:

```
String database="G:\\databs.mdb";
String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + database+";DriverID=22;READONLY=true"; 

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question reveals that you are already aware of the `sysWOW64` subsystem, so keep in mind that on a 64-bit Windows machine there are two "ODBC Administrator" applications...

`C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` for 64-bit applications , and

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` for the 32-bit world

...(yes, the naming does seem a bit backward), and on 64-bit machines the one you can see from `Control Panel > Administrative Tools` is the 64-bit one.

System DSNs that you create in one will not be visible in the other. When configuring DSNs for a particular application you have to "mind your own bit-ness". :)

Comment: :Sir can you be more elaborate..where do i need to specify the dsn..why the error comes so?

Comment: @Jayanth (1) re: "where do i need to specify the dsn" -- You need to determine whether your application is operating in the 32-bit or 64-bit space and then run the corresponding "ODBC Administrator" application to create your DSN. (2) re: "why the error comes so" -- As my answer suggested, sometimes the 32-bit and 64-bit "worlds" cannot see each other. If your 32-bit app needs a System DSN and you create it in the 64-bit "world" then your app won't know that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so much is the machine 64 bit, its is your JVM 64 bit. If it is, use the 64 bit admin, if not use the 32 bit one (as you know where they both are).